# Why are there zombie packages in my yarn.lock file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, single-page-application, yarnpkg

We deploy all of our applications as Docker containers, and, as part of the build process, run them through a container scan to block deployments that include vulnerabilities with known fixes.

I'm currently getting failures in the security scan because my `yarn.lock` contains `cacache@^12.0.2`. But as far as I can tell, there is absolutely no reason for that to be in the lock file. For example, if I run `yarn why` it seems to have no reason to include the package:

```
/app # yarn why cacache@^12.0.2
yarn why v1.22.4
[1/4] Why do we have the module "cacache@^12.0.2"...?
[2/4] Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4] Finding dependency...
error We couldn't find a match!
Done in 1.30s.
```

How do I get rid of these insecure and unnecessary dependencies?

I've tried wiping the lock file and rebuilding from scratch. After doing that, the problematic 12.0.2 version is still there. I've also tried running the `autoclean` command, which does remove a substantial amount of unnecessary heft, but does not remove these apparently redundant and definitely insecure dependencies.

Update: as requested, here is part of the package file with the dependencies listed:

```
{
  ... redacted
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.29.0",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^5.29.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^5.29.0",
    "@sentry/vue": "^5.29.0",
    "amplitude-js": "^7.4.1",
    "buefy": "^0.9.3",
    "cacache": "^15.0.6",
    "element-ui": "^2.14.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "idle-vue": "^2.0.5",
    "is-svg": "^4.2.2",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "launchdarkly-js-client-sdk": "^2.19.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "logrocket": "^1.0.7",
    "logrocket-vuex": "^0.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "view-design": "^4.4.0",
    "vue-feather-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "vue-resize-directive": "^1.2.0",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@olavoparno/jest-badges-readme": "^1.5.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "clipboardy": "^2.3.0",
    "coffee-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "coffeescript": "^2.5.1",
    "cypress": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "pug": "^3.0.1",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-jest": "^4.0.0-rc.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes — I will update the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
➜ yarn why cacache
yarn why v1.21.1
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "cacache"...?
[2/4]   Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4]   Finding dependency...
[4/4]   Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "cacache@15.0.6"
info Has been hoisted to "cacache"
info Reasons this module exists
   - Specified in "dependencies"
   - Hoisted from "nuxt#@nuxt#webpack#terser-webpack-plugin#cacache"
=> Found "webpack#cacache@12.0.4"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "nuxt#@nuxt#webpack#webpack#terser-webpack-plugin" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "nuxt#@nuxt#webpack#webpack#terser-webpack-plugin#cacache"
```

(Posted as an answer because this would make a terrible comment.)

Then follow up with `yarn why terser-webpack-plugin` of course.

Comment: Got it. So perhaps the lesson here is that `yarn why` doesn't work with version callouts. That's too bad.

Comment: @josephkibe AFAIK it just takes the package name, which (to me) doesn't imply allowing a version specification, but the docs don't really go into detail.

Comment: FWIW I had a similar issue and `yarn why <package>` helped me realize that I forgot to save `package.json` after removing the vulnerable version entry from it.

Answer (score 0):

@Dave nicely answered the question. However, there is something more you can do to optimize your packages.

1. You can use packages like node-prune and ModClean to clean up the unwanted dependencies.
2. Use `--production` flag on npm install.